Session null on next Middleware with supabase getUser
I got my session in the localStorage, but when I try to access the data in Middleware of Next, auth.getUser() is equal to null, and I dunno how to fix it.
enter image description here
enter image description here
Auth.getSession()
Expecting:
The session with user and token.
Resulted: null
